# lua require function does not find my required file on iOS

Tags: ios, lua, require

I'm new to lua, this might be something quite simple, but I couldn't figure it out. I did all night search, read some posts here, but are not quite what I'm looking for. I finally worked out a lame solution that i'm not happy with, so I'm here to ask for help.

I'm trying to embed lua inside c++, and this program will run as part of an app on the iPhone, as we know, every iPhone app has a resource bundle, and the lua scripts are distributed with the bundle.

```
// I printed out the bundle path:
bundle directory /var/mobile/Applications/C6CEF090-B99A-4B9B-ADAC-F0BEF46B6EA4/LuaThirdTry.app
```

Say I have two script files (main.lua, mylib.lua) in the same folder, I put them in my Xcode project, organized like this:

```
somefolder
|--main.lua
|--mylib.lua
```

and main.lua is as below:

```
--main.lua
print(package.path)
require("mylib")
```

obviously I want to use code from mylib.lua, however, I got error from lua vm:

```
/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;./?.lua
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (...090-B99A-4B9B-ADAC-F0BEF46B6EA4/LuaThirdTry.app/test.lua:5: module 'mylib' not found:
    no field package.preload['mylib']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/mylib.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/mylib/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/mylib.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/mylib/init.lua'
    no file './mylib.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/mylib.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './mylib.so')
```

When I add a line modifying package.path, I got it running correctly:

```
--main.lua modified
print(package.path)
package.path = package.path .. ";/var/mobile/Applications/C6CEF090-B99A-4B9B-ADAC-F0BEF46B6EA4/LuaThirdTry.app/?.lua"
require("mylib")
```

But this is an absolute path, which should definitely be avoided.
One way to solve this problem is to provide lua a function from c, which returns the full path of lua file in ipa bundle at runtime to lua script, and concatenate the package.path with that path, but I think that shouldn't be the "official" way of doing this.

I noticed "./?.lua" inside package.path variable, I just wonder why mylib.lua can't be found, isn't it for files within the same directory?

Sorry for the blah, so the question is: how do I do the "require" decently in iOS environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, "." is not the folder containing main.lua, but a working directory (such as where xcode runs from). The app that runs your script probably runs it via a path, like

```
lua /full/path/to/your/main.lua
```

So having `./?.lua` in LUA_PATH does not help here. Instead, you should have the script run a command to determine where it is running from, and append that to `package.path`. This should be the path part of `arg[0]`. So you could try (not tested):

```
local scriptPath = arg[0]
local dir = string.match(scriptPath, '^.*/')
package.path = package.path .. ';' .. dir .. '?.lua'
```

The `arg` is automatically populated by the interpreter, see [Section 6 of Lua ref man](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#6).

You definitely don't need C to do what you want.

Comment: Hi Schollii, thanks for the answer, I have no idea how to retrieve the path of the running script, any clue?

Comment: This is what I show above: the arg array is automatically populated for you by the interpreter. I have updated the answer, hth.

Comment: Yeah, it worked with standalone lua interpreter perfectly, I've tried that, thanks. Sadly however, I don't seem to have arg available with lua embedded in c++ code.

Comment: @Bryophyte Your question as posted does not say anything about embedding Lua in C++ code. If this is actually what you are doing, this critical and your question should reflect that. If this is part of your solution, what my solution is saying is that you don't need any C++ function callable from Lua. Please clarify.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't realize the difference. I've made my change on my question.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I think it's a good idea to set up the path in lua, but I don't know which function gets the "current" path of the running script.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I finally find a good answer and the job is done, thank to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4156038/1317816).

So, the solution is to modify the path within c++ code, add this function

```
#include <string>

int setLuaPath(lua_State* L, const char* path) {
    lua_getglobal(L, "package");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "path"); // get field "path" from table at top of stack (-1)
    std::string cur_path = lua_tostring(L, -1); // grab path string from top of stack
    cur_path.append(";"); // do your path magic here
    cur_path.append(path);
    lua_pop(L, 1); // get rid of the string on the stack we just pushed on line 5
    lua_pushstring(L, cur_path.c_str()); // push the new one
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "path"); // set the field "path" in table at -2 with value at top of stack
    lua_pop(L, 1); // get rid of package table from top of stack
    return 0; // all done!
}
```

and then, call this function when init lua_State:

```
// yourfile.cpp
void runLua() {
    lua_State *L;
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    OCCaller oc_caller;
    std::string bundlePath = oc_caller.get_ios_bundle_path();
    bundlePath.append("/?.lua");
    setLuaPath(L, bundlePath.c_str());

    ....
}
```

your oc_caller class might look like this:

```
// OCCaller.h
#ifndef __LuaThirdTry__OCCaller__
#define __LuaThirdTry__OCCaller__

#include <iostream>

class OCCaller {
public:
    OCCaller();
    ~OCCaller();
    std::string get_ios_bundle_path();

};

#endif
```

impl file:

```
// OCCaller.mm
#include "OCCaller.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

OCCaller::OCCaller() { }
OCCaller::~OCCaller() { }

std::string OCCaller::get_ios_bundle_path() {
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath];
    return std::string([bundlePath UTF8String]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a revision on Bryophyte's answer. To me, this was far too complex. I'm also not sure why he did all these extra classes and used C++ strings instead of NSStrings. Here is my revised and hopefully easier to understand iOS code based on this solution:

```
-(void)addBundlePathToLuaState:(lua_State*)L
{ 
    lua_getglobal(L, "package");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "path"); // get field "path" from table at top of stack (-1)

    const char* current_path_const = lua_tostring(L, -1); // grab path string from top of stack
    NSString* current_path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s;%@/?.lua", current_path_const, [[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]];

    lua_pop(L, 1); // get rid of the string on the stack we just pushed on line 5
    lua_pushstring(L, [current_path UTF8String]); // push the new one
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "path"); // set the field "path" in table at -2 with value at top of stack
    lua_pop(L, 1); // get rid of package table from top of stack
}
```