# How to let lua load another lua script?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to embed **Lua 5.2** into my C program.

I want to let the Lua script to be able to `require` and load another script. How to do it?

Suppose the Lua part has such file structure:

```
lua_script
  - main.lua
  + utils
    - custom_loader.lua
  + globals
    - scene_globals.lua
    - scene_levels.lua
```

The `main.lua` will try to `require` and import functions from `custom_loader.lua`, and so on...

Is it possible to do this without writing a kind-of wrapper in C?
Can the Lua script automagically just load everything it needs?

(Ps. I don't really *need* sandboxing for now, so it's okay for the script to do what it want.)

Comment: I think `require` is just a function that you can define as you please.

Comment: @KerrekSB so, I should just push a C function as `require` and do `luaL_loadfile()` for every files that the script want?

Comment: Yes, one possibility is to write your own searcher system that resolves `require` calls. But there may be simpler solutions using built-in facilities.

Comment: `require('lua_script.utils.custom_loader')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As decribed by the Lua require [man page](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html), it searches for the file in a path.

This path can be defined in C.
Have a look to this post : ["Setting the global LUA_PATH variable from C++/C"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125971/setting-the-global-lua-path-variable-from-c-c)

The require function is very pratical to load modules and libraries defined in .lua files.

Comment: @Tito: yes I think it does.